# wkhtml to pdf not supporting japanese characters

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf tool in my application to generate pdf . But for japanese characters are not coming in pdf.
wkhtmltopdf tool is not supporting for japanese characters. Is there any way to resolve this ???

Comment: I am using centos operating system

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue is related to your system font, because wkhtmltopdf is just converting html to PDF file.

Can you check this question?

[wkhtmltopdf and chinese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833954/wkhtmltopdf-and-chinese-characters)