# Installing fonts that render Mandarin characters with WKHTMLtoPDF on Heroku

Tags: heroku, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to get wkhtmltopdf to render a PDF that contains Mandarin characters on Heroku.

After quite a lot of research, I followed the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833954/wkhtmltopdf-and-chinese-characters) and installed all of the Chinese fonts into a `fonts/` directory in my root folder from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fonts#Chinese.2C_Japanese.2C_and_Korean_Fonts), as well as `ttf-droid`. The Chinese fonts where `.ttc` files, so I tried them as that, then converted them to `ttf`s when that didn't work.

Has anyone got any idea how to get these to work?

Answer (score 1):

For those that want a solution(ish), I ended up importing the font in CSS.